# Where can I get the Microft SharePoint assemblies?

Tags: .net, sharepoint, dll, powershell

I am trying to workup an automated tool for SharePoint interaction through a Powershell script. Am running into a SharePoint.dll not found issue and upon looking it up(including previous posts in StackOverflow), it seems its available in the server. I do not have access to a Sharepoint installation at the moment. Is there some place I could download it or if any one had access to a copy can it be shared?

Thanks
Barun

Comment: Wow - you are able to develop a tool to integrate with SharePoint without actually having a SharePoint server to test it against - are you some sort of coding Jedi? ;)

Comment: @Ryan - Maybe a deranged wannabe Jedi...I need to check with a shrink on that one soon ;)
I do have a SharePoint server to test against only that the files & dlls in the server are not accessible to me...as I am just trying to hack up an automation utility...
Is clear that is? ;)

Comment: I can only guess at the organisational dysfunction that means you're developing against something that you can't get access to! Anyway - slightly more helpful answer coming shortly. Good luck young Jedi!

Comment: Yes its a fight against the organization and the sysadmins :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to clarify - a copy of Microsoft.SharePoint.dll will allow you to reference and compile against it but it won't actually work unless its running on a machine with SharePoint properly installed.

A few options for you.

1. You can [download, for free Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=EF93E453-75F1-45DF-8C6F-4565E8549C2A&displaylang=en) - but it needs to run on a Windows Server OS (2003+).
2. You can download (for free again) [Windows Server 2010 Foundation and get it running on Windows 7 64bit client OS for a development environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx).
3. You can download a [30 day trial of MOSS on a preconfigured VHD](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?familyid=67F93DCB-ADA8-4DB5-A47B-DF17E14B2C74&displaylang=en) - basically a complete pre-configured virtual server - but you need Hyper-V or VMWare Server running on a 64 bit CPU to run this virtual server.
4. There is a [hack to get WSS running on Vista](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/bambooteamblog/archive/2008/05/21/how-to-install-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0-sp1-on-vista-x64-x86.aspx) - but its unsupported and the licensing/legal situation is unclear - very probably its in breach.
5. You could use [SharePoint's web services](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_webservices/tutorials/article.php/c8805) then you won't need the dll or access to the SharePoint server apart through the web services - which assuming you can browse it you should be able to get.

UPDATE: Option (3) is no longer available. As workaround, you could download [a VHD with SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 Standard (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26113), and install SharePoint 2010 on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ryan for the options. I am considering SharePoint Web services at the moment and it looks good. Will also try out the VM option. 
What eludes me here is if I was building a client for SQL server I get drivers etc separately. But for SharePoint server why does a developer building a client needs to have access to the "Server Installation"?

Like I don't not need to know the installation details for SQL Server 2005 if I am building a client against it nor do I need to use any files from the server setup? Am I coming across as very stupid here or is there a little bit of sense in it?

Comment: That is true - up to a point. But try writing anything non trivial with just drivers and not being able to actually test against a SQL server database. Don't fight the force young Jedi - its just the way it is! ;)

Comment: Just thought we may be talking at x-purposes a little. Databases ('real' ones anyway) are designed to be connected to across a network using drivers. SharePoint's object model just isnt - if you need access from a different machine you're only choice is through its web services.

Comment: Hmm...think I got the source of the confusion, because I actually am working on a tool which would "remotely" upload & download files from SharePoint...am not writing any module to integrate with or enhance the Sharepoint server itself...so we were talking at x-purposes...and it seems for remote operations web service is the only solution...thanks for the help Master Ryan! ;)

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot download it from any 3rd party sites. It is not licensed that way. If you own a copy of Windows Server (2003 or 2008), you will be able to download WSS 3.0 from Microsoft's public download location. From this, you can get Microsoft.SharePoint.dll.

-Oisin

Comment: @Oisin - Thanks for the info. I will try to look into the option of getting a SharePoint server access? Does it install on any virtual machines that have Windows Server?

Comment: SharePoint 2007 installs fine on any VM running Server 2003/2008. SharePoint 2010 requires Server 2008, but also runs fine on a VM.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft.SharePoint.dll itself epends on lots of other DLL's and a Database underneath SharePoint. You must have SharePoint to test against it.

But just yesterday I ran on some stuff called SharePoint testing using [Typemock isolator](http://www.google.lv/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=sharepoint+typemock+isolator).
What it does is it fakes SharePoint objects without needing all that database and other stuff. There is a [nice presentation](http://www.blackmarble.com/ConferencePapers/2009/Developer%20Testing%20SharePoint%20using%20Typemock%20Isolator.pdf) available. Havent tried myself, but maybe that leads you on the path. See if it helps you.

Comment: Thanks Janis...it certainly looks like a good implementation and a very good presentation explaining it but seems its proprietary which may be a catch...will follow it up nevertheless...had at least some newer concepts related to mocking :)

Answer (score 1):

There is NuGet package for the Sharepoint client. This is the fastest way....